# Why aren't NPM scripts relaying arguments correctly on Windows PowerShell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, npm

Been vexed by this all day.  Using Powershell 7.2

Given script index.js with this single line

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

And a package.json of

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "index": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

When I invoke this command:

```
node index -a -b -c
```

Then I see

```
[
  'C:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\michael.morris\\Projects\\Fleetcor\\ucx-cucumber\\index.js',
  '-a',
  '-b',
  '-c'
]
```

And when I run

```
npm run index -- -a -b -c
```

Then I should get the same output, but I don't. The -a -b -c args are gone.  The -- should prevent that.

This really sucks. I have to be doing something wrong right?

Node v14.15.5, NPM 8.1.3

EDIT: The mystery deepens.  I decided to try this across different shells. The above behavior was on PowerShell 7.2 running stand alone since I don't have admin permissions on this machine.  I tried PS 5 which came with the machine, same problem.  So I went to the command prompt - and it worked as it should...

So I can proceed with my work, but it would help to know exactly what's up or if this is a bug of some sort.

Comment: `--` is mostly used for `end of arguments`. Take a look at [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382)

Comment: @Christopher It means the end of options and beginning of filename arguments, it doesn't mean the end of arguments.

Comment: Yeah can't edit it anymore. Thanks for the correct. :)

Comment: And in the case of `npm run`, `--` is supposed to separate the `npm` options from the arguments to the script.

Comment: "_I have to be doing something wrong right?_" - no, you are not. You must have something in your local environment getting in the way of that statement, but this code is exactly right. This works as it should.

Comment: Edited the question. Seems like we have a shell bug of some sort. Thanks for the reassurance that I was getting the command right Randy, that got me to rethink the problem and try other shells.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scripts arguments starting with -- are removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72259748/scripts-arguments-starting-with-are-removed)