# Scripts arguments starting with -- are removed

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell-core

In node 14 I had the following script

```json
scripts: {
  "test": "node test.js",
}
```

Then I ran it with the following command `npm run test -- --value '10'` this gave the output

```sh
node test.js "--value" "10"
```

But when I switch to node 16 every argument that starts with -- gets removed

So whenI run `npm run test -- --value '10'` this gives the output

```sh
node test.js "10"
```

Where did "--value" go?

Comment: How does your `test.js` look? If I create a file with `console.log(process.argv)` in it and run your example, I get the expected output of `[ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/tmp/test.js', '--value', '10' ]`.

Comment: @CherryDT we use yargs to parse the parameters, I'm on windows and using powershell, but I don't think that is the cause, but if I use `console.log(process.argv)` i get the following `['C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', 'C:\\projects\\test\\test.js', '10']`

Comment: I was testing Linux first, but I tested Windows now as well (both cmd and powershell) and I still get the `--value`. What are your exact node and npm versions?

Comment: node is v16.15.0 and npm is 8.10.0

Comment: Does it happen also when you run `node test.js --value 10` directly, or only via `npm`?

Comment: Seems to be a npm issue, I had a different machine that was on `npm 8.1.2` where it was working correctly, but when I upgraded to `npm 8.10.0` it stopped working

Comment: This is very odd. I tried with the same versions now and I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244772/discussion-between-cherrydt-and-peter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% about the root cause, but I can now explain the semi-root causes and ways to work around it.

It appears that while on my machine there is only an `npm.cmd` file in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, on yours there is also an `npm.ps1` file. It appears this file is created only in some install/upgrade paths, and your node upgrade seems to cause this file to be created.

That means that when you run `npm` in PowerShell, it is invoking an `ExternalScript` and not an `Application`. For this reason, semantics for calling cmdlets apply to the invocation and not semantics for calling native commands/applications.

These semantics include the use of `--` to stop parsing further arguments. That means that in this case *PowerShell* will consume the `--` token so it never arrives to npm! And in turn, npm now being called with `npm run test --value 10` without `--` will swallow `--value` because it's considered an argument to npm and not to the script you want to invoke.

Quote from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.2#the-end-of-parameters-token---):

> ### The end-of-parameters token (`--`)
>
> The end-of-parameters token (`--`) indicates that all arguments following it are to be passed in their actual form as though double quotes were placed around them. For example, using `--` you can output the string `-InputObject` without using quotes or having it interpreted as a parameter

It doesn't state here that it applies only to cmdlets and external scripts but my testing showed that that's the case.

There are four possible solutions I can think of:

- Create an alias to manually point `npm` to `npm.cmd` instead of `npm.ps1`: `Set-Alias -Name npm -Value npm.cmd`
- Rename/remove `npm.ps1` to make sure PowerShell uses `npm.cmd` instead
- Add another `--` in front which is consumed by PowerShell to allow the *following* `--` to be consumed by npm: `npm run test -- -- --value 10` or `npm -- run test -- --value 10`
- Quote the `--`: `npm run test '--' --value 10`

Comment: I know I had nothing to do with this question, but I just wanted to thank you because your post helped me solve a really frustrating issue surrounding NPM being a ps1 file. Only one of my Node versions had a NPM.ps1 file, and it was completely messing up my code. (Arguments weren't being parsed correctly). I had no idea why until I actually checked what file was being invoked when I ran NPM. And sure enough, it was a ps1... and only for that version. Renamed the ps1 and now all is good!

Anyway, thank you!